# It is possible to /fill or /clone in a round area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

It is possible to /fill or /clone in a round area in only one command block? I wondered about this because /testfor command can detect player in a round area, so why not with these?
It's all of my question.
Thank

Comment: Did you search anywhere for an answer before posting here?

Comment: Yes; just re-read the question, I've edited it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately in-game you cannot. Try editing your world with **[MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/)**, there's an option there to create spheres.